# Setting margin or padding for all the controls in a container

Tags: android

On an activity in a `LinearLayout` I have a number of controls most of which are EditText. I wonder, is there any way to set margin or padding for those controls in one fell swoop instead of having setting it for each control one by one?

Comment: give "padding" or margins to that container

Comment: Put every UI entities in a single layout say a Linearlayout then add padding or margin for that layout only

Comment: It might sound crazy but thats one way to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the margin or padding to the LinearLayout itself. On doing so then the margin and padding will apply for all its child views.(The Edit Texts)